# display custom taxonomy value

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have created custom post type estate_property,requirement,service and I have shared property_category  and property_action_category taxonomy among them. But I m unable to display taxonomy values of requirement post type.

This is my template file code..

```
$property_category          =   get_the_term_list($post_id, 'property_category', '', ', ', '');

$property_action_category   =   get_the_term_list($post_id, 'property_action_category', '', ', ', 
'');
<?php print $property_action_category; ?> 
        <?php if( $property_action_category!='') {
                print ' '.__('and','wpestate').' ';
                } 
              print $property_category;?>
```

I am getting correct post_id. So anybody has any idea??
I want to display post under requirement post type in this template and related taxonomy.

Comment: In which template is this, taxonomy.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <ul class="property-categories">
        <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'property_category', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' ); ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="property-actions">
        <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'property_action_category', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're sure they're taxonomies? Have you tried <?php $taxonomies=get_taxonomies(); ?>